# Sort each Object inside Array of Objects by its values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have this function below to sort the keys of an object accordly their values.

```
var obj = {"A": 50, "B": 10, "C": 150 };

var ordered = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b) {
            return obj[a] > obj[b] ? -1 :
                   obj[b] > obj[a] ? 1 : 0;
        });

console.log(ordered); // => [C, A, B];
```

However, when I have an Array of Objects, this function returns nothing.

For an Array of objects like this below:

```
var objs = [
    {"A": 50, "B": 10, "C": 150 },
    {"A": 60, "B": 100, "C": 10 },
    {"A": 150, "B": 100, "C": 30 } 
]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
let op =[];
objs.forEach((obj) => {
    let ordered = {};
     Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach((a,b) => {
      ordered = obj[a] > obj[b] ? -1 : obj[b] > obj[a] ? 1 : 0;
    });
  op.push(ordered);
});

console.log(op);
```

But this function returns an error: **Identifier 'op' has already been declared.**

I need to return something similar to the example above, but applied to each object. The result would be:

```
console.log(ordered); // => [[C, A, B], [B, A, C], [A, B, C]]
```

Comment: `Identifier 'op' has already been declared.` You've only declared `op` once in the code you posted, though...

Comment: If you’re executing this code in your console by copy-pasting it, you shouldn’t paste the `let op` line. You could also wrap it in a block.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is the entire function. It seemed weird to me as well... Maybe there is another issue in this code.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you describe, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are putting the sort logic in the `forEach` which isn't going to work. Since you already have a sort that works for you, 
to get your desired output, you can just make it a function and `map` it over the array:

```js
function ordered(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return obj[a] > obj[b] ? -1 :
      obj[b] > obj[a] ? 1 : 0;
  });
}


var objs = [
    {"A": 50, "B": 10, "C": 150 },
    {"A": 60, "B": 100, "C": 10 },
    {"A": 150, "B": 100, "C": 30 } 
]


console.log(objs.map(ordered))
```

If you prefer the `forEach` code, you just need a couple changes:

```js
var objs = [
    {"A": 50, "B": 10, "C": 150 },
    {"A": 60, "B": 100, "C": 10 },
    {"A": 150, "B": 100, "C": 30 } 
]

let op =[];

objs.forEach((obj) => {                                // just on forEach
    let ordered = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => 
        obj[a] > obj[b] ? -1 : obj[b] > obj[a] ? 1 : 0 // sort 
    )
    op.push(ordered);                                  // push sorted array
});

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Great, both solutions returned the expected values

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce the error you describe, but here's another way to do it, using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const objs = [
    {"A": 50, "B": 10, "C": 150 },
    {"A": 60, "B": 100, "C": 10 },
    {"A": 150, "B": 100, "C": 30 } 
];

const ordered = objs.map(o => Object.entries(o)
                                    .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1)
                                    .map(([k]) => k));

console.log(ordered);
```